# Bathc file to loop through a text file and create two variables based on each line

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to loop through a text file with a simple list of user numbers...

e.g.

```
002
003
004
005
```

...and create two variables based on each line - the first being the full number (e.g. 002) and the second with the leading zero's stripped out (e.g. 2).

My example script so far is;

```
REM  *******************************
REM  Get User number from text File
REM  *******************************

for /F %%x in (C:\Scripts\users.txt) do (
set host=%%x

REM  ********************************************************
REM  Remove Leading Zero's from user number if less than 100
REM  ********************************************************

for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%host%") DO SET host=%%A

REM  *************************************
REM  Set User IP Address from user number
REM  *************************************

set userip=18.10.%host%.100

net use Z: \\%userip%\d$ /user:%%xcom\master password
xcopy "\\%userip%\d$\Time Sheet" "\\networklocation\users\%%xcom\Time Sheet" /E /C /R /I /K /Y
net use Z: /delete

)
```

As soon as I try running the batch file it closes immediately which tells me that it's failing somewhere!

The idea is to loop through all the users, create a mapped drive to an IP address based on their username and then copy the time sheet database from their local machine to a network location.

I've tried scrapping together various bits of code I've found off t'internet but I'm no coding master...and therefore having no luck seeing what is wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the for metavariables or implement `delayed expansion` because you cannot `set and use` a variable within a loop otherwise.

```
REM  *******************************
REM  Get User number from text File
REM  *******************************

for /F %%x in (C:\Scripts\users.txt) do (

REM  ********************************************************
REM  Remove Leading Zero's from user number if less than 100
REM  ********************************************************

for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%%x") DO (

REM  *************************************
REM  Set User IP Address from user number
REM  *************************************


net use Z: \\18.10.%%A.100\d$ /user:%%xcom\master password
xcopy "\\18.10.%%A.100\d$\Time Sheet" "\\networklocation\users\%%xcom\Time Sheet" /E /C /R /I /K /Y
net use Z: /delete
)
)
```

Comment: Fantastic!! I didn't realise it would be as simple as that...I didn't realise you can't 'Set' & 'Use' a variable within a loop. Many thanks :)